# Grub is not booting Windows 10 anymore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

The problem: Whenever I chose Windows 10 boot mgr on GRUB the laptop restarts and comes back to GRUB screen

The root: I was updating my Ubuntu version when I lost my internet connectivity and update stopped even after connection was made. I restarted my laptop and updated Ubuntu by running some commands in non-GUI mode (GUI mode wasn't working)

I have seen so many problems similar problems on askubuntu, here are some of them that I tried:
[First help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725290/windows-doesnt-start-anymore-from-the-grub-boot-menu), the problem with this is that there is no `chainloader +1` in my file
[Second help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/665986/windows-10-does-not-boot-from-grub) I can't boot into windows to try it.

Many solutions ask to use Windows CD, but I don't have that either.

More things I tried: 
Updating grub.

Selecting windows from the boot menu that appears after pressing `esc` key on bootup.

I ran some commands to repair grub [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Nothing has worked as of now.

Results from bootinfoscript: [are here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hfyHfKYFXB/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: @karel tried that but still not getting into windows!

Comment: @karel I now have the result.txt from bootinfoscript, which part of it should I post here because it is too long

Comment: If the Boot-Repair Boot Info Script is too long to paste entirely, you can copy/paste it in [Ubuntu Pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and provide a link to it in your question.

Comment: @karel Done! The link is in the question

Comment: It looks you actually have no windows installation. It is only Windows recovery environment. You may writ windows 10 image on USB using Unetbootin. Boot and repair windows.

Comment: You show NTFS partition, but no Windows boot files in the ESP - efi system partition. You cannot fix that from Linux but need your Windows repair flash drive to reinstall its boot files. https://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader